# JavaScript on change function working not well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JavaScript code which works with HTML select tag.

```
$(function() {
  $('#to_name').on('change',function() {
    if( $(this).val()=="<?php echo $ceo_chunks[0];?> <?php echo $ceo_chunks[1];?> <?php echo $ceo_chunks[2]?>") {
      $('#to_designation').val('<?php echo $ceo_chunks[3];?>');
      $('#dear_sir').val('<?php echo $ceo_chunks[0]?> <?php echo $ceo_last_name;?>') ;

      if( $(this).val()=="<?php echo $liaison_one_chunks[0];?> <?php echo $liaison_one_chunks[1];?> <?php echo $liaison_one_chunks[2]?>") {
        $('#to_designation').val('<?php echo $liaison_one_chunks[3]?>')
        $('#dear_sir').val('<?php echo $liaison_one_chunks[0]?> <?php echo $liaison_one_last_name;?>')
        $("#liaison_one").show()
        $("#dear_liaison_one").show()
      } else {
        $("#ceo").hide()
        $("#liaison_two").hide()
        $("#dear_ceo").hide()
        $("#dear_liaison_two").hide()
      }

      if( $(this).val()=="<?php echo $liaison_two_chunks[0];?> <?php echo $liaison_two_chunks[1];?> <?php echo $liaison_two_chunks[2]?>") {
        $('#to_designation').val('<?php echo $liaison_two_chunks[3]?>')
        $('#dear_sir').val('<?php echo $liaison_two_chunks[0]?> <?php echo $liaison_two_last_name;?>')
        $("#liaison_two").show()
        $("#dear_liaison_two").show()
      } else {
        $("#ceo").hide()
        $("#liaison_one").hide()
        $("#dear_ceo").hide()
        $("#dear_liaison_one").hide()
      }
    };
  });
});
```

and here is html code

```
<select name="to_name" id="to_name">
        <option value="<?php echo $ceo_chunks[0];?> <?php echo $ceo_chunks[1];?> <?php echo $ceo_chunks[2]?>"><?php echo $ceo_chunks[0];?> <?php echo $ceo_chunks[1];?> <?php echo $ceo_chunks[2]?></option>

        <option value="<?php echo $liaison_one_chunks[0];?> <?php echo $liaison_one_chunks[1];?> <?php echo $liaison_one_chunks[2]?>"><?php echo $liaison_one_chunks[0];?> <?php echo $liaison_one_chunks[1];?> <?php echo $liaison_one_chunks[2]?></option>

        <option value="<?php echo $liaison_two_chunks[0];?> <?php echo $liaison_two_chunks[1];?> <?php echo $liaison_two_chunks[2]?>"><?php echo $liaison_two_chunks[0];?> <?php echo $liaison_two_chunks[1];?> <?php echo $liaison_two_chunks[2]?></option>
      </select>



        <br>

        <select name="to_designation" id="to_designation">
        <option value="<?php echo $ceo_chunks[3]?>" id="ceo"><?php echo $ceo_chunks[3]?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo $liaison_one_chunks[3]?>" id="liaison_one"><?php echo $liaison_one_chunks[3]?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo $liaison_two_chunks[3]?>"id="liaison_two"><?php echo $liaison_two_chunks[3]?></option>
      </select>


<div id="dear_ceo" style="margin-top:10px; width:auto">

      <input type="text" name="dear_sir" id="dear_ceo" value="Dear <?php echo $ceo_chunks[0]?> <?php echo $ceo_last_name;
?>"/>
      </div>
      <div id="dear_liaison_one" style="margin-top:10px; width:auto; display:none">
        <input type="text" name="dear_sir" id="dear_liaison_one" value="Dear <?php echo $liaison_one_chunks[0]?> <?php echo $liaison_one_last_name;?>"/>
      </div>
      <div id="dear_liaison_two" style="margin-top:10px; width:auto; display:none">
        <input type="text" name="dear_sir" id="dear_liaison_two" value="Dear <?php echo $liaison_two_chunks[0]?> <?php echo $liaison_two_last_name;?>"/>
      </div>
```

My function works very well for select tag but it's not working with input type text.

How can I fix that?

Comment: What about you declare javascript variables for those PHP values to make the code more readable? If you print-out PHP variables into javascript like that, you're gonna regret it sooner or later.

Comment: @TomášZato am new in coding can you suggest me

Comment: I suggest you format your javascript code - see my edit. It's much easier to find errors then.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use semicolons at the end of line (when appropriate). I know they are not mandatory but consider them as a good practice.

You also have a semicolon at the end of if-clause at the end. It's probably not braking anything but just in case...

Try replacing spaces with underscores (_).

For example:

```
<?php echo $ceo_chunks[0];?> <?php echo $ceo_chunks[1];?> <?php echo $ceo_chunks[2]?>
```

would become

```
<?php echo $ceo_chunks[0];?>_<?php echo $ceo_chunks[1];?>_<?php echo $ceo_chunks[2]?>
```

And check if you can alert the value of the changed input correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a closing bracket clearly missing for your first if statement.
Please close the bracket. There is no logical error in your code.

```
 $(function() {
      $('#to_name').on('change',function(){


      if( $(this).val()=="<?php echo $ceo_chunks[0];?> <?php echo $ceo_chunks[1];?> <?php echo $ceo_chunks[2]?>"){
        $('#to_designation').val('<?php echo $ceo_chunks[3];?>')
        $('#dear_sir').val('<?php echo $ceo_chunks[0]?> <?php echo $ceo_last_name;?>')

        /*$("#ceo").show()
        $("#dear_ceo").show()*/

    //}    ---uncomment this ---
```

also include a terminating semi-colon everytime you are calling a function. For example

```
 if( $(this).val()=="<?php echo $ceo_chunks[0];?> <?php echo $ceo_chunks[1];?> <?php echo $ceo_chunks[2]?>"){
        $('#to_designation').val('<?php echo $ceo_chunks[3];?>');
        $('#dear_sir').val('<?php echo $ceo_chunks[0]?> <?php echo $ceo_last_name;?>');
    }
```